# Is there documentation on how to install scripts?

Tags: discussion, meta, scripts

Is there documentation, or at least links, on how to how to install JavaScript scripts for your web browser of choice? Most of the FAQ seems to be about how to create StackApps, rather than how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see the [wiki page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) for the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag.

Comment: .. and on [Super User](http://superuser.com/q/252046/4377)